# Copying data from 1 server to another to only replace/overwrite 0KB files in a specific folder tree

Tags: powershell, data-structures, copy-paste

I am very new to PS and I was wondering if someone could help me with a PS scripting problem.

I need to recover data from a server that was using `MailMeter Archiver` as a back-up tool (not my idea). When the company upgraded to `MSS2008R2` on a newer server they tried to copy the back-up from the old server to the new server.

Although a lot of the data copied over, it left a load of **`0KB`** files and folder structure. The data is still intact on the old server, but live data has been updated, so I can't just copy the archived data over.

I have scripted a search to find all the **`0KB`** files in their folder structure,

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\%Folders% -Recurse -Filter *.* | Where {$_.Length -eq 0} | Select-Object FullName | Add-Content -Path C:\Test\%filename%
```

but I am stuck on how I would script reading of the output file, searching the old server directory, copying the files and overwriting the **`0KB`** files in the folder structure with the original data... there is `~37000` data items missing... Pointers? Anyone?

Comment: Why the %'s? Are you calling this from a batch script? Powershell variables are `$filename`

Comment: No, it was just a quick way to hide our business servers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you want to do. So basically overwrite all 0kb files with the originals from the old structure? Like this?

```
$oldDir = "C:\server1"
$newDir = "C:\server2"

# get all 0kb files
Get-ChildItem $newDir -Recurse -Filter *.* | where { $_.Length -eq 0 } | foreach {
    # get original path and copy/overwrite
    Copy-Item $_.FullName.Replace($newDir, $oldDir) $_.FullName -Force -Confirm:$false
}
```

Let me know if this is what you need.

Comment: HI marzse, thanks for your input, the logic looks like this script might do the trick. I will keep you posted

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks marsze that absolutely did the trick, did a few tests and all good. So once change req has gone in, I will be implementing this!